# On handling OnClick for a button, is having an async anonymous/arrow function bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

Just as the title says. I'm using React with Typescript. I'm not sure how to explain it further.

Here is the context:

```js
<button onClick={async () => await addUser(user)}>Submit</button>
```

```js
async function addUser(user: User) : Promise<void> { 
    await fetch('user', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            UserId: user.id,
            UserName: user.user_name,
            Email: user.email
        })
    }).then((Resp) => Resp.json())
        .then((Res) => console.log(Res))
}
```

Let me know what you think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, using an async function directly as an event handler for an onClick event is not necessarily bad practice, but it can lead to unexpected behavior and might not be the best approach in certain situations..
For example, if an error occurs within the async function, it won't be caught properly by the event handler, leaving the user in the dark about what is happening.
Moreover, thinking about high-scalable applications, you may have issues with maintainability. Using an async arrow function inline can make the code less readable, making it more difficult to maintain.

A better approach to your snippet would be:

```
async function addUser(user: User): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('user', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                UserId: user.id,
                UserName: user.user_name,
                Email: user.email
            })
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error adding user:', error);
        // Handle error as needed
    }
}


<button onClick={() => addUser(user)}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot you could just drop the async and await in the arrow function (for the button). I wasn't too worried about error handling at the moment, but thank you for the additional help!